# Tabla dinámica Angular

Tags: angular, rest, tabla-dinámica

Solicito ayuda porque no se como proceder. Tengo un proyecto en el que realizo una llamada REST a una API del Ayuntamiento de Madrid. Recibo un .json con los datos de unos eventos próximos, y quiero mostrar parte de esa respuesta en forma de tabla. La cuestión es, que desconozco el número de eventos que voy a recibir por lo que necesito que la tabla sea dinámica en cuestión de filas.

Se me había ocurrido recorrer la respuesta y cada apartado que necesito meterlo en un array:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.wS.getEventos().subscribe(data =>{
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
          this.evento = [data.title]; 
          this.fechaInicio = [data.dtstart];
          this.fechaFin = [data.dtend];
          this.precio = [data.precio];
          this.enlace = [data.enlace];
      }  
    
    },
      error =>{
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

Y luego, para hacer una prueba he intentado mostrar solo el nombre del evento:

```
<div>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">EVENTO</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let event of evento">{{event.evento}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Pero no me muestra nada, imagino que está mal formulado.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme? , **Gracias de antemano**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu bucle for estás machacando contínuamente los datos, no estás creando un array y rellenándolo. De hecho, puedes ahorrarte el bucle:

```
//puedes declarar una interface Evento con los atributos esperados
public eventos: Evento[];

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.wS.getEventos().subscribe(data =>{
    this.eventos = data;
  },
  error =>{
    console.error(error);
  });
}
```

Y recorrer el array obtenido directamente de la respuesta:

```
<div>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">EVENTO</th>
            <th scope="col">FECHA INICIO</th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let evento of eventos">
            <td >{{evento.title}}</td>
            <td >{{evento.dtstart}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Cierto, luego me di cuenta de que estaba machacando los dato, aunque tu forma sigue siendo más "limpia" que la que después hice. Así que gracias.